# Why and how algebraic structures emerged in mathematics?

Tags: abstract-algebra, math-history, motivation

For example, why we study Group Theory to prove general results for all instead of specifically studying $\mathbb Z$ (or any other set) closed under some operation?

What makes algebra and those generalizations such an useful tool for practical and theoretical purposes? How abstract algebra emerged?

Comment: See e.g. Leo Corry's book  *Modern Algebra and the Rise of Mathematical Structures*.

Comment: Just downloaded the book. It looks pretty interesting. Thanks for advice

Comment: This is what mathematicians do. They inspect specific constructs, see that they have similarities to other objects. They look for the minimal amount of similarities that are enough so that the objects are still "alike". They define a term for objects with properties that make them similar. Then they work on this abstract level, guided by rules about how those objects behave.

Comment: This is a very good question, but *much* too broad for this site - entire books have been written on the topic. For example, I strongly recommend Gray's [**Plato's Ghost**](https://press.princeton.edu/titles/8833.html). I'll merely point out that you have to distinguish between a few fundamentally different aspects: why mathematicians (tend to) find the study of abstractions of concrete objects interesting for its own sake; why such abstractions (often) have applications to the original concrete objects; and how historically that interest became dominant and those applications became apparent.

Comment: @B.Swan This is what *research* mathematicians do *nowadays*. How this came to be is an interesting question. But I must agree that it is far too broad.

Comment: I would like you people to evaluate my understanding so far: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3310815/554493